# How should I verify that a log message did not trigger when testing Python code?

Tags: python, unit-testing, logging

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34920727 deals with testing log outputs

But what if I want to test that messages did not trigger, how do I do that. I am using **unittest**.
For example:

```py
    def test_HandlerEnabled(self):
        with self.assertLogs(level='DEBUG') as fake_log:
            uut=myHandler.Setup(tag="foo", enabled=True, out_stream='log')
            uut.Debug("testing")
        self.assertEqual(fake_log.output, ["DEBUG:root:foo: testing"])

    def test_HandlerDisabled(self):
        with self.assertLogs(level='DEBUG') as fake_log:
            uut=myHandler.Setup(tag="foo", enabled=False, out_stream='log')
            uut.Debug("testing")

        self.AssertThatNoLogsTriggeredOnRoot(fake_log.output) # <<<<<<<<<< here
```

I hereby, confirm that I have attempted to find an answer to this question myself.

Comment: I would suggest using the [caplog](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/logging.html#caplog-fixture) fixture from pytest.

Comment: @zvone even if I were to use caplog from pytest, what method allows me to check that nothing triggered on the logs?

Comment: Adapt some of the code in https://plumberjack.blogspot.com/2010/09/unit-testing-and-logging.html

Comment: Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35871815/python-3-unit-testing-assert-logger-not-called)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to upgrade to python 3.11 so I could use assertNoLogs:

```
def test_HandlerDisabled(self):
    with self.assertLogs(level='DEBUG') as fake_log:
        uut=myHandler.Setup(tag="foo", enabled=False, out_stream='log')
        uut.Debug("testing")
        self.assertNoLogs('root', level = 'DEBUG') #<<<<<< use this
```

For previous versions, as @frankfalse suggests, implement your own method. Example here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/61381576/9962617